# Applications sharing common domain objects from database

Tags: java, caching, orm, eclipselink

First, some background. At my work, we have many applications that share a similar (or an exact overlap of) domain objects with regards to the business area of our company. We have standardized on EclipseLink as our ORM solution and currently have a domain project that holds all these data concepts. When this data is needed, it is trivial to grab the domain project's jar and add the needed classnames into the new app's persistence.xml file.

This works great from a code re-use perspective, however, since this is happening across disparate apps, caching is happening locally inside the apps, not across them. I've looked into EclipseLink's cache coordination, but this seems to be more interested in caching one app's data across a cluster. Instead, I'm thinking about writing an app to fetch the domain objects from the database and serve them up via webservice for all of the other apps that need said data.

My question is, is this an appropriate architecture for caching objects from the database, or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Have you measured and decided, based on those measurements, that you needed to cache? If not, don't cache, and trust your database for being fast. Tune your queries and indices. Accessing the data through a web service is probably going to be much slower and much less flexible than executing a database query.

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically, you'd be creating another app which should handle database access and caching (to avoid going to the database all the time).
This would be a fine architectural pattern, but be aware that each app should no longer "trivially grab the domain project's jar"; you're gonna need to define how the apps access this central data access and caching app.
I think you're going to be in for some challenges with that, but I'll be happy to read comments and other answers.